# How to save a postman request body in one place and pass when run

Tags: javascript, json, postman

How to set the request body in one place and reuse it in multiple requests so I save effort maintaining test scripts if the build changes.

I am using postman for test automation in a dynamically changing environment. the json body structure might change from build to another,
I have to update each request separately.

Here is a sample body where i pass the values from global setter

```
{        "phone": "{{phone}}",
         "income": {{income}} 
}
```

these variables are defined in the prerequest as

```
pm.globals.set("phone", "xxxxxxxx953");
pm.globals.set("income",10);
```

TIA

Comment: So would you like a piece of JSON with your environment vars within it, that you can change in a single place? I'm trying to understand what you actually need.

Comment: Why are you using postman ? Why aren't you just calling your API with a library ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By what you say, I understand you want to have a mutable json body structure defined only in one place and then reuse it by specifying different values on different requests.
You can achieve this, by using the following:

Include the value of a variable in the *Body > raw* tab from each request you want to configure this way, for instance:

```
{{rawBody}}
```

[image]

Define the JSON object to be sent in the **folder** (or even collection) Pre-request Script:

```
var obj = {
        phone: "{{phone}}",
        income: "{{income}}"
    };
pm.environment.set("rawBody", JSON.stringify(obj));
```

[image]

Finally, on the request *Pre-request Script* tab specify the values corresponding to the request:

```
pm.environment.set("phone", "xxxxxxxx953");
pm.environment.set("income", 10);
```

[image]

By this, you can handle many requests and modify their json body text at once. Obviously, if you want to specify different values for each request you will have to specify them on the request *Pre-request Script* tab.

Comment: This is a nice solution - except from my meddling you can actually set a value to null.. the best you can get is "" - which is a shame!